# Read million records from xlsx using Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a xlsx file that has nearly a million records. I am trying to read the file using Apache POI. However, it throws an outOfMemory error. I tried increasing the Java heap space, however it does not fix the issue. Is there any work around or alternative API for reading such large files?

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted so far.

Comment: Please be aware that asking for "alternative API" is off topic on SO. You might want to rephrase the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use streaming api for apache POI - it allows you to read sheet rows randomly without fetching whole document into memory at once.
Check this out for more details.
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf

Comment: Its pure site vandalism to dovnwote and not leaving a comment explaining why.